# Initialize property on the first access in Javascript

Tags: javascript, getter

I would like to create an object using constructor `A` which has property `x` that will be initialized first time when it is accessed. Also, any object of type `A` must follow the same behavior. I have tried something like this:

```
function A() {
};

A.prototype = {
    get x() {
        delete this.x;  // try to delete getter
        this.x = 4;
        return 3;
    }
};

var a = new A();

console.log(a.x);  // 3
console.log(a.x);  // 3
```

I was expecting to see `3` and `4` in the console instead of `3` and `3`.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: You always do `return 3;` in the getter.

Comment: As I tried to delete the getter, this value `3` would be returned only first time. But deletion of getter doesn't work as I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Object.defineProperty() instead of inline getters:

```
function A() {};


Object.defineProperty(A.prototype, "x", {
    get: function() {
        Object.defineProperty(this, "x", {
               enumerable: true,
             configurable: true,
                    value: 4
        });
        return 3;
    }    
});


var a = new A();

console.log(a.x); // 3
console.log(a.x); // 4
```

Object.defineProperty() allows us to re-configure the "this" object (the instance, not the proto) with an "own property" primitive value at first run. basically, it dis-ambiguates between this meaning "prototype" and this meaning "own" inside the getter-as-a-method. there might be a way to do that with inline getters, but ODP is more standard anyway, and it actually works as expected.

keep in mind that you can set A.prototype.x to 3, and if needed, ask obj.hasOwnProperty("x") vs if(obj.x) to toggle between local/inherited properties, so you might not even need a getter method...

Comment: my initial answer forgot to include the cosmetic enumerable and configurable properties to make it walk and talk like a "regularly-assigned" property.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are always returning value `3` in the getter there is nothing strange in getting this value in the console every time.

The workaround that I would suggest is having a boolean value, that indicates, if the `x` property was accessed any time before:

```
A.prototype = {
    inited: false,
    get x() {
        if (!this.inited) {
            this.inited = true;
            return 3;
        }
        return 4;
    }
};
```

[**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4RQr6/1/)

Comment: I know that I return 3 in the getter. That should not be a problem since I tried to delete that getter on the first access. But this deleting getter doesn't work for some reason that I don't understand.

Comment: I am aware of that workaround. But this is not what I actually want. In my situation I have bunch of properties that should work the same. For each property if I create its `inited` property I would have too complex code and too big object in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Although I accepted answer from dandavis which I found very comprehensive, I have found another possible solution:

```
function A() {
    return {
        get x() {
            delete this.x;
            this.x = 4;
            return 3;
        }
    }
}

var a = new A();

console.log(a.x); // 3
console.log(a.x); // 4
```

Comment: note that returning something besides "this" in a constructor breaks prototype inheritance. that might not matter for certain projects, but it's good to keep in mind.